# Is it possible to specify an ISO Date with a timezone (i.e. GMT offset) but without a time?

Tags: swift, date, iso8601

I'm trying to see if you can specify a date with a timezone in ISO but without also specifying a time.

This may seem odd to ask about having a timezone without actually having a time, but technically a date represents a range between two times... the 24-hour period spanning from midnight to midnight, and that 'midnight' has to be in a timezone.

In our case, we have an API that wants to say 'Filter things on-or-before date X and on-or-after date Y' and we want the user to specify 'April 9th' (in their time zone) for both to get all things that happen on that day.

Of course we solve this by adding a day to the first date, then changing it to a pure 'before', but the front-end is required to do that math. We can't do it on the backend because having to send a date with a time means we would be sending April 9th at midnight, then on the backend adding a day to that, but what if someone passed in 4pm?

We could fail the date if it has a non-midnight time, but then we're back to why pass it in the first place.

So again, can you have a date with a timezone but not have a time component?

Comment: By the way, did you consider saving time changes when a day has either 23 or 25 hours?

Comment: That's precisely why I am asking about specifying no time. I'm only interested in a date, regardless of how many hours are in it.  In other words, a person pointing at a calendar on the wall and saying 'I want to see what happened on that date!' where 'that date' is relative to where they are.  Make sense?

Comment: Use `ISO8601DateFormatter` and set the `formatOptions` to `[.withFullDate, .withTimeZone]`.

Comment: @vadian, that was the missing piece!  Put it in an answer and I'll mark it as such.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To *decode* ISO8601 dates only with year-month-day and time zone set the appropriate `formatOptions` of the `ISO8601DateFormatter`

```
let isoFormatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
isoFormatter.formatOptions = [.withFullDate, .withTimeZone]
```

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks! That's what I was doing wrong. :)

Answer (score 1):

If by *time zone* you mean a UTC offset (as used with ISO 8601 dates with times), this is no problem. If by time zone you mean a true time zone with historic, present and known future offsets from UTC, including for example summer time/DST, like America/New_York or North American Eastern Time, then ISO 8601 does not support that, neither for dates with nor without time of day.

```
2020-04-25-04:00
```

This is perfectly valid ISO 8601 for April 25 this year at offset -04:00. So you may use it for representing the interval from 2020-04-25T00:00-04:00 (inclusive) to 2020-04-26T00:00-04:00 (exclusive). Which would then be equivalent to 2020-04-25T04:00Z to 2020-04-26T04:00Z (Z meaning UTC).

### Java example code

I don’t know any Swift, so cannot tell you how to format or parse such a string in Swift. In Java formatting it is not bad. Example:

```
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(2020, Month.APRIL, 25);
    String isoOffsetDateString = date
            .atStartOfDay(ZoneId.of("America/New_York"))
            .format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE);
    System.out.println(isoOffsetDateString);
```

Output:

> 2020-04-25-04:00

I am using Java’s built-in `ISO_OFFSET_DATE` formatter. The documentation informs us that this formnatter is:

> The ISO date formatter that formats or parses a date with an offset,
>   such as '2011-12-03+01:00'.

Parsing the string and producing the start and end of the day takes a little more:

```
    TemporalAccessor parsed
            = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE.parse(isoOffsetDateString);
    Instant start = LocalDate.from(parsed)
            .atStartOfDay(ZoneOffset.from(parsed))
            .toInstant();
    Instant end = start.plus(1, ChronoUnit.DAYS);

    System.out.println("From " + start + " inclusive to " + end + " exclusive");
```

> From 2020-04-25T04:00:00Z inclusive to 2020-04-26T04:00:00Z exclusive

I have opted to convert to `Instant`, the class for a moment in time independent of offset or time zone. Instants print in UTC, as the trailing `Z` on each says. In your Java code you may prefer not to do this conversion or to do a different conversion, all depending on circumstances.

### Link

- [Documentation of `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_OFFSET_DATE)

Comment: Tried a few different ways to use this with Swift's ISO8601DateFormatter, but it keeps saying it's not a valid format.  Any chance you have some code that shows how this is used?  You can use Java if you want as this technically affects our backend too.

Comment: @MarkA.Donohoe If your aim is to use `ISO8601DateFormatter`, then you should update your question. The format is valid but it doesn't mean it is supported by `ISO8601DateFormatter`. You can always use standard `DateFormatter`.

Comment: But you're saying it's an ISO8601 date, not just 'a' date.  Yes I can use a custom date formatter, but I could make that date formatter go YEAR-TIMEZONE-DAY-RANDOMVERB-MONTH because you can specify any format you want.  I am specifically trying to adhere to ISO8601-standard formats and I can't seem to find any that are just date-with-timezone, but you said that is a standard.  Can you provide a reference to that?  I don't mind writing a custom formatter, but again, we're trying to adhere to standards. You're saying it's supported so I'm asking for validation.  Make sense?

Comment: For the record, I do see ISO8601 dates *without* a timezone, but none *with* a timezone... not that I have found anyway.

Comment: I am sorry, Mark, I don’t know any Swift, so can’t help you there. I know exactly how to do in Java, but it seems that that won’t help you.

Comment: Actually, it may help!  Again, others may be coming here from Java too so it would be helpful to update your answer with a code example. You can even call out that you aren't doing it in Swift, but it is possible, and here's how in Java. I'd happily vote your answer up.  The important thing is something that illustrates that *is* a valid ISO format because it's ensuring we're following accepted, industry-wide standards and not just a user-defined date format.

Comment: Thanks, Mark, for the encouragement. I have edited.